# Python kivy filechooser reads wrong path

Tags: kivy

I'm trying to use Kivy as a GUI for my python app, which needs to read a file from the filesystem.
However, in some cases the kivy filechooser read wrong path or nothing causing an IndexError while I'm trying to set the read path for a text of a textfield.
I use the default example for reading files learned from http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.filechooser.html
The relevant part of my app is in this function, where an exception handling is added as a not a good approach to handle this :)

```
 def load(self, path, filename):
    '''
    this will load the file and dismiss the dialog
    '''
    print "Loading file..."

    print "filename:",filename
    print "path:",path
    try:
        self.selected_file = filename[0]
        self.file_text_input.text = self.selected_file
        self.dismiss_popup()
    except IndexError as ie:
        print "Something made a boo-boo...try again"+str(ie)
        self.dismiss_popup()
        self.show_popup("ERROR","Somehow I couldn't load the file:\nCheck the permissions or move it to other place")
```

self.show_popup() is just a helper function, which shows a popup with the set function params.

The basic error is that filename[0] will throw an IndexError since it does not read the correct path.
I'm using Linux with python2.7, and somethimes when I select a file in my home folder, the filename variable stores nothing, while path variable stores misteriously a random folder, for instance, /media, /opt, etc.

Did anyone meet this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out why it was handled uncorrectly.
All the failures are caused by Kivy's

> FileChooserListView

, which enables to click on folders and files via a list, but it also makes it possible to have a littel '>' sign at the beginning of every list element, which are directories.
I realized that when I used these '>' signs, then I get wrong path, but if I always clicks on the directories' list elements then everything works fine.
However, that little '>' cannot be disabled (for now), so the best and fastest alternate solution is using

> FileChooserIconView

instead!
Now everything is good :)